# What emulator settings can I set my android AVD to to get a "large" screen?

Tags: android-emulator, size, screen, screen-size

I am almost finished (finally!) with my android application. I need to test it on a "large" screen size. What can I set the AVD on to make it a "large" screen?

Answer (score 1):

To add to vikramjb's answer, you might also want to change the screen density.

For example, to emulate my 7inches eLocity tablet I set the resoltion to WVGA800 and the abstracted LCD density to 160

Answer (score 0):

Goto your Android SDK and AVD Manager and select your the device you are currently using. Click on Edit on the same screen, on the try changing the skin size. Of-course you can always create a new device for a new screen size.

correct me if i am wrong. HTH